# Attempting to add a JavaScript graph to a rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Trying to add a JavaScript graph. Go this from the Google developers page. It gives this error:

> ExecJS::RuntimeError in Scores#index
>
> SyntaxError: [stdin]:8:1: reserved word 'function'

and highlights this line:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Not really sure what it means, tried googling it but couldn't find any solutions.

```
HTML

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
  

Javascript
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);
    
    function drawBasic() {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('number', 'X');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
    
          data.addRows([
            [0, 0],   [1, 10],  [2, 23],  [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9],
            [6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
            [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
            [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42], [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],
            [24, 60], [25, 50], [26, 52], [27, 51], [28, 49], [29, 53],
            [30, 55], [31, 60], [32, 61], [33, 59], [34, 62], [35, 65],
            [36, 62], [37, 58], [38, 55], [39, 61], [40, 64], [41, 65],
            [42, 63], [43, 66], [44, 67], [45, 69], [46, 69], [47, 70],
            [48, 72], [49, 68], [50, 66], [51, 65], [52, 67], [53, 70],
            [54, 71], [55, 72], [56, 73], [57, 75], [58, 70], [59, 68],
            [60, 64], [61, 60], [62, 65], [63, 67], [64, 68], [65, 69],
            [66, 70], [67, 72], [68, 75], [69, 80]
          ]);
    
          var options = {
            hAxis: {
              title: 'Time'
            },
            vAxis: {
              title: 'Popularity'
            }
          };
    
          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }`
```

Comment: I tried to run your code and I got no error. Do you have gem 'execjs' in Gemfile ?

Turbolinks description is here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#how-turbolinks-works